# How to convert image data to multipart /form-data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using `react-dropzone-uploader` for uploading my image to an API but the API needs the data in `multipart/form-data`. I am not able to convert it into `form-data`.

Here is my code :

```
const onDropHandler = (files) => {
    let formData= new FormData()
    formData.append('file',files[0])
    axios.post('/web/v1.0/upload',{formData}).then(response=>{
    console.log(response.data)
})
```

I am getting this error:

> 401 unauthorized

Comment: Your API probably requires you to pass in an Access Token in an `Authorization` header. Check if that's the case. If it is, send the request along with the Request header.

Comment: @SiddAjmera No,It doesn't require any authorization token.I have already checked that.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I have checked it using postman.The only thing i require is multipart/form-data.

Comment: An answer to this similar question suggests using a `Blob`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392690/converting-base64-image-to-multipart-form-data-and-sending-with-jquery

Comment: what exactly are you using to make the API call? Axios / fetch API?

Comment: @SiddAjmera axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the `Content-Type` header to `'multipart/form-data'`

Give this a try:

```
const onDropHandler = (files) => {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', files[0])
    API.post('/web/v1.0/upload', {
      formData
    }, {
      headers: headers
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
```

**PS:** I'm assuming that your `API.post` method accepts a config Object that supports `headers`.